# Angular4 how to get events from http stream

Tags: angular

I'm using wildduck as email server. Can someone help me how to get events from this api https://api.wildduck.email/#api-Users-GetUpdates using Angular 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as explain in the page [api](https://api.wildduck.email/#api-Users-GetUpdates) do the following:

`var stream = new EventSource('/users/59fc66a03e54454869460e45/updates');
stream.onmessage = function(e) {
  console.log(JSON.parse(e.data));
};`

Comment: Thanks. I thought that in angular I need to use something different